# Lambda expressions are not supported in -source 6

Tags: java, maven

when i package my code, i get this error `Error:(13,48) java: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 6`.

I tried installing different JDK, but doesnt change. I tried jdk 11, 1.8, 13.

Comment: If you see the same error after you install a newer JDK, then you aren't using the compiler from the newer one. To figure out why, what OS are you using?

Comment: Im using windows 10

Comment: How are you building your package? And can you show example code, including a pom file. I suggest just creating a small project that you can use for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify in the pom the java version your project uses. Add this section to your `pom.xml` to specify java 8 for instance

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```